# How to use Redis to manage connections for tornado websocket

Tags: python, websocket, redis, tornado

I have a Tornado server with Tornadio2 handling the WebSocket and TornadoRedis by which I publish realtime messages to the clients (code was merged from several examples).

```
redis_client = tornadoredis.Client(config.get('cache', 'host'), int(config.get('cache', 'port')))
redis_client.connect()

class RealtimeHandler(tornadio2.conn.SocketConnection):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RealtimeHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.listen()

    @tornado.gen.engine
    def listen(self):
        self.client = tornadoredis.Client(config.get('cache', 'host'), int(config.get('cache', 'port')))
        self.client.connect()
        yield tornado.gen.Task(self.client.subscribe, 'invalidation')
        self.client.listen(self.on_message)

    def on_event(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        if name == 'invalidation':
            redis_client.publish('invalidation', kwargs['args'])

    def on_message(self, msg):
        if msg.kind == 'message':
            self.send(msg.body)

    def on_close(self):
        if self.client.subscribed:
            self.client.unsubscribe('invalidation')
            self.client.disconnect()
```

This code works, and now, I want to store the connections in Redis to accomplish 2 things:
1. Support redundancy for my server
2. Be able to use the connections even if I restart Tornado

I saw several examples where a global list is used to save the connections but this of course won't solve my issues above.

So, how do I accomplish this?

On a different note, is this a good setup? How is it compared to node.js with socket.io and redis?

Comment: you are going to have 1 redis connection per subscribed client which can be a problem at some point.

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli thanks. How do you suggest I handle it?

Comment: you can use one single pub/sub and do the routing in python (i did something similar here https://gist.github.com/tbarbugli/5612981)